# Replace address from google iframe with custom field value in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dictionary, field

I have one wordpress site where i need to show google route map with start point and destination. Every point is one custom field like start_address and final_point. How can i get value from each field and replace in iframe code below.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m28!1m12!1m3!1d1418111.0445191974!2d21.54961556245587!3d46.0361738916186!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m13!3e6!4m5!1s0x4745984ba35c59c3%3A0xf70074a3e558491!2sArad!3m2!1d46.166667!2d21.316667!4m5!1s0x474c6788fd2c1cd5%3A0x3ade9d214e3390b4!2sSibiu!3m2!1d45.792784!2d24.152068999999997!5e0!3m2!1sro!2sro!4v1433447238580" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

I need to replace Arad and Sibiu with value from custom fields.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That isn't possible I'm afraid, the content of an iframe cannot be edited in that way as it's information pulled from an external website. To do what you want you would need to add your own custom Google Map to the page and tap into it using custom fields. More info can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map).